# Как получить значение String из метода

Tags: java, android, android-textview

Есть код

```
    public String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
    switch (networkType) {
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
            return "2G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
            return "3G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
            return "4G";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

Как мне из этого получить значение (2g, 3g, 4g или ничего) и вывести его на экран через `TextView`?

Comment: ээ .. `textView.setText(getNetworkClass(this);` и причем xml в тэгах?